# Interaction of \bm with optional argument

Tags: macros, bm

What's going on here?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\myfuncA}[0]{A}
\newcommand{\myfuncB}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\myfuncC}[1][]{#1}

\begin{document}
\[
    \bm{\myfuncA} % works
    \bm{\myfuncB{B}} % works
    \textbf{\myfuncC[C]} % works
    \bm{\myfuncC[C]} % doesn't work
\]
\end{document}
```

**Edit 1:** Would someone from overleaf like to implement the solution in David Carlilse's answer?

**Edit 2:** I'm told that's not likely to be useful. Never mind.

Comment: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/554

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation (`texdoc bm`):

> **3.5 Strange failures**
>
> In order to get the correct spacing, `\bm` has to ‘investigate’ the definition of the commands in its argument. It is possible that some strange constructions could ‘confuse’ this investigation. If this happens then LaTeX will almost certainly stop with a strange error. This should not happen with any of the math symbols defined in the base LaTeX or AMS distributions, or any commands defined in terms of those symbols using normal LaTeX math constructs. However if some command does fail to work inside `\bm` you should always be able to surround it with an extra set of braces \bm{{\cmd}} rather than \bm{\cmd}. \bm will not then attempt to set the correct spacing, so you may need to set it explicitly, for instance, for a relation, `\bm{\mathrel{\cmd}}`.

For your example changing the last line to

```
\bm{{\myfuncC[C]}}
```

gets it to compile.

Comment: ah but it should (and used to) work,

Comment: I just glanced at the source code and I have to admit that when I got to `\def\bm#1#2` I was left puzzled since I couldn't figure out how that macro template would be able to correctly parse any of the examples and the internal comments seem to be describing something completely different from the user command. ‍♂️

Comment: the first \def\bm is just an internal setup command it gets defined again later (saves one slot in the hash table, this is old code and I was short of space:-)

Comment: That might be worth a note on the next update to the package, or maybe even going completely nuts and using a different name. I'd thought by 1996 everyone was on "big" TeX.

Comment: I knew so quickly what you meant as I'd just stumbled over that while checking what was happening and it's my code:-)  so yes I added an issue at github so this doesn't get lost but probably i'll change those names.

Answer (score 7):

> What's going on here?

Specifically what's going on is this

```
% \changes{v1.1g}{2004/01/23}{Use kernel version of
%                             \cs{@ifnextchar} (pr/3501)}
```

`\bm` makes `\@ifnextchar` more or less safe inside `\bm` but for hmm "a while" `\newcommand` has not used `\@ifnextchar`.

Locally adding

```
    \let\kernel@ifnextchar\@ifnextchar
```

so they both get made safe produces

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}


\makeatletter
\let\bm@end\relax
\begingroup
\catcode`\'=\active
\catcode`\_=\active
\@firstofone{\endgroup
\def\bm@general#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \begingroup
    \let\bm\@firstofone
    \let\hm\@firstofone
    \global\let\bm@command\@empty
    \let\@let@token\@empty
    \let\protect\@empty
    \let\@typeset@protect\@empty
    \def\bm@mathchoice{\bm@m@thchoice#1}%
    \def\bm@group{\bm@gr@up#1}%
    \let\bm@table#2%
    \let\left\holdinginserts
    \let\right\left
    \let\mskip\mkern
    \let\hskip\kern
    \let\bm@prime\copy
    \let_\relax
    \def'{\bm@prime\prime\relax}%
    \def\@ifnextchar##1##2##3##4{%
      \if##1##4%
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
      \else
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
      \fi
      {##2##4}{##3{##4}}}%
% \changes{v1.1g}{2004/01/23}{Use kernel version of
%                             \cs{@ifnextchar} (pr/3501)}
    \let\kernel@ifnextchar\@ifnextchar
    \def\GenericWarning##1##2{%
      \unvcopy{\GenericWarning{##1}{##2}}}%
    \def\GenericError##1##2##3##4{%
      \unvcopy{\GenericError{##1}{##2}{##3}{##4}}}%
    \let\DN@\copy
    \let\FN@\copy
    \let\next@\copy
    \global\let\bm@first\@empty
    \ifx\uproot@\undefined\else
       \def\root##1\of##2{{\root##1\of{##2}}}%
    \fi
    \def\mathaccentV##1{\mathaccent"\accentclass@}%
    \let\@ifnext\@ifnextchar
    \let\measure@lhs\copy
    \let \rel@break\copy
    \let \bin@break\copy
    \let \after@open\copy
    \let \after@close\copy
    \let\ifmmode\iftrue
     \let\install@mathalphabet\def
     \let\getanddefine@fonts\@gobbletwo
     #3%
    \def\select@group##1##2##3##4{{%
      \protect##1{##4}}}%
    \def\use@mathgroup##1##2##3{{%
      \protect\use@mathgroup##1{##2}{##3}}}%
    \bm@expand#5\bm@end
  \endgroup
  #4}
}
\outer\def\bm@end{\@@end}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\myfuncA}[0]{A}
\newcommand{\myfuncB}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\myfuncC}[1][]{#1}

\begin{document}
\[
    \bm{\myfuncA} % works
    \bm{\myfuncB{B}} % works
    \textbf{\myfuncC[C]} % works
%\tracingall
    \bm{\myfuncC[C]} % doesn't work
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I add this to the preamble along with `\usepackage{bm}`, the pdf doesn't compile. When I add it without `\usepackage{bm}`, it compiles but with a list of errors.

Comment: @mjc ah sorry I actually did it by fixing the package locally, I'll post a preamble version in a second (there are a couple of timing issues)

Comment: @mjc sorry about that version that works added, although you may want to simply add the one line `\let...` to a local copy of `bm.sty` instead.

Comment: Thanks for this. I use overleaf, and I'm guessing I can't edit packages locally there, so maybe I'll tag this post to let the overleaf team know about this fix. Nice to have a reply from the creator of the package :)

Comment: @mjc overleaf won't be able to fix it until I push  out an update, users can update a local copy but overleaf won't want to change standard files for all kinds of reasons.  You can add that code to your preamble or upload a modified bm.sty into your project